# @apply in polymer is not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am new to Polymer and ASP.NET. I am trying to develop a ASP.NET project using Polymer. But when I use `@apply()` in Polymer to customize style it give a error like this :

> The name 'apply' does not exist in the current context

This is my code

```
<dom-module id="simple-todo">
 <template>
  <style is="custom-style">
  .flex {
    @apply(--layout-horizontal);
  }
        </style>
        <div class="container flex">
            <div>one</div>
            <div>two</div>
            <div>three</div>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Thanx in advance !

Comment: you likely should put this in a html file, not a cshtml file

Comment: thank you for the respond. is that polymer not working in cshtml ??

Comment: i think so since the cshtml is a razor file and `@` is magic for razor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` has a special meaning in a razor file. This means it is the start of some server code(C#). So razor engine things that `apply` is a C# method! @ will also do Html encode on the result of the expression following.

You can use `Html.Raw()` method to handle this case. Raw method will not encode the result

```
<dom-module id="simple-todo">
    <template>
        <style is="custom-style">
  .flex {    
            @Html.Raw("@apply(--layout-horizontal);")
        }
        </style>
        <div class="container flex">
            <div>one</div>
            <div>two</div>
            <div>three</div>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do double @

```
@@apply(--layout-horizontal);
```